# Measuring "model complexity": Using degrees of freedom or number of coefficients?

Tags: linear-model, degrees-of-freedom

I made two linear models whose specs are:

**Model 1:**

n. of coef: 60
dof: 939

**Model 2:**

n. of coef: 176
dof: 844

I want to be able to infer whether Model 2 is significantly more complex compared to Model 1.

Are these statistics enough to infer this and are there more statistics I could look at?

Also, if Model 2 has more coef, but less dof, then is Model 2 more complex or simpler than Model 1?

Comment: Inference and "significance" would seem to have no role here: either one model is more "complex" than another or not.  DoF tells you about how much data you have whereas the coefficients are a property of the model.  The answers to your question should be clear.

Comment: @whuber What do you mean by "how much data you have"? Model 2 is supposed to be a better fit, so this sounds confusing if it had "less data" than Model 1.

Comment: Usually DoF equals the number of observations minus the number of parameters.  Thus, for any given model, differences in DoF indicate differences in number of observations (and that's all).  If that's not what it means here, then please clarify.

Comment: @whuber Are parameters synonymous to coefficients? Is DoF a measure of goodness of fit?

Comment: It looks like it's time to do a little research, because that will spare you a great deal of confusion: please search our site for the terms you are using, including "parameter" and "degrees of freedom."

Comment: If both models were fit to the same data, the the sum #paramters+#df would be the same for both models. Those sums are not the same, so this cannot be two fits to the same data. So it can't make sense to compare goodness of fits. How do you defined "complexity"? I think you need to define your question much more carefully in order to get an answer.

Comment: @HarveryMotulsky They are to the same data. But it's possible that either of the models has omitted some data because of some problems in the fitting (this happens sometimes in R).